# домен широковещания Ipv6

Tags: ipv6

Что делать с широковещательными( any, broad, group,) запросами в ipv6 сетях, с глобальными ipv6 адресами.  Как будет выглядеть домен широковещания в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 0):

ttl=1 на пакетах бродкаста и мультикаста в ipv4. в ipv6 соответственно также Hop Limit = 1. такие пакеты не уходят за пределы роутера.